# New line in ListBox with bound data

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm putting data to ListBox from a list of objects using this simple code:

```
<ListBox Name="lbxListaZadan">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel xml:space="preserve" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
                <TextBlock Text="&#10;" />
                <TextBlock Text="Priorytet: " />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding priority}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Instead of expected output:

```
Task1
Priorytet: 1
Task2
Priorytet:2
Task3
Priorytet: 3
```

I'm getting:

```
Task1Priorytet: 1

Task2Priorytet: 2

Task3Priorytet: 3
```

Why is the newline in a place I would not expect it to be, and how the hell can I reach the expected output in listbox.

Comment: You are getting the newline... look at the gap between the lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                         
         <TextBlock Text="Priorytet: " />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding priority}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

A newline character can only work inside a single TextBlock, not between two of them.

Answer (score 2):

You can put 2 `TextBlocks` in vertical `StackPanel`

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding priority, StringFormat='Priorytet: {0}'}"  />
</StackPanel>
```

also instead of 2 `TextBlocks` for `priority` you can use one with `StringFormat`

Answer (score 2):

The `Environment.NewLine` would only have the expected effect, if the texts are in the same `TextBlock`.
WPF then renders the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` with the new line in mind, which causes a line break.

To achieve the wanted behavior, you'd have add a vertical layout element:

```
<ListBox Name="lbxListaZadan">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel xml:space="preserve" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Priorytet: " />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding priority}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```